# LED driver inrush current

Tags: led-driver, inrush-current

I'm using a LDD-700L Meanwell LED driver to drive 5 Power LEDs in series. The LEDs require a Vfd of 3.9VDC and a current of 700mA. The driver seems OK, except during startup. When voltage is applied to the LED driver, a current peak of 8A is shown for 10us on the scope. This is also the case without connecting LEDs at the output of the LED driver. In my previous design I connected 8 strings of 5 LEDs to my PCB, resulting into a voltage dip and high current peak at startup. I've been looking for a solution, because of the voltage drop, other devices connected to the 24V 20A power supply, shut down and need to restart for a moment. From my research there are multiple options to limit inrush currents.

1. Limit the current at startup using a thermistor at the input
2. Gradually increasing the voltage at the input
3. Create my own current source, probably using a LDO (which often have a soft start build in)

The main question is; How to limit the inrush current created by the LED driver?

Hopefully someone is able to help!

Thanks,

Joggem

*Some pictures:*

Current peak at startup 1x LDD-700L in purple (100mV/A +/- 8A)
[image: Current peak at startup 1x LDD-700L in purple (100mV/A +/- 8A)]

Current peak at startup 8x LDD-700L in purple (10mV/A)
[image: Current peak at startup 8x LDD-700L in purple (10mV/A)]

Comment: How are you applying voltage to the drivers? If they're hooked up to the 24v supply at power on it should gradually ramp up to 24v which will limit current. If you're switching them on with a transistor to +24v, a simple solution is to switch them one at a time or just leave them connected and use drivers with an output enable or dim to off function.

Comment: The LDD-700L has an output enable pin so that you can leave it connected to power, which will avoid in rush current on on/off. Have you tried using that? The smaller in rush on power supply start may be acceptable, especially since the value you measure is less than half your power supply capacity at 24v.

Comment: It may be that the inrush is inherent to the design of the LED driver. For example, if there is a boost input stage, the boost capacitor will immediately charge up the moment you connect the mains. Cheap drivers will not have a current limiting circuit to limit this inrush current.

Comment: @mr_js From the almost perfect square wave shape of the current, what we are probably seeing is the buck converter current limiting as it charges the output capacitors. Using the dim/enable pin would probably help here since it would let more of that current come from the input capacitors (which would already be charged) or could be used to charge them more gradually or one at a time.

Comment: you may use some П- filter (C-L-C) before the input, ex  100uF -100uH -100uF, and connect your LED driver via this filter, instead to connect it directly

Comment: Thank you for the usefull information. What I'm going to do now is:
- Connect the On/Off pin to the 24Vin, haven't tried that;
- Try using a filter connected to the LED driver;
- If the above did not work, find a more suitable LED driver with inrush protection;

Thank you! I'll give an update on the results.